# What happened to my midi device files?

Tags: input-devices, midi

I've been working on a personal project which involves parsing a binary stream of midi data from a controller. The way I had been doing it was reading from `/dev/dmmidi1`. Over the weekend I upgraded from Kubuntu 12.04 to Kubuntu 14.04. Now, when I plug in my midi controller, there are no device files that look like ones that would correspond to my controller.

When I run `aplaymidi -l`, the output shows the device that I expect. Why am I not seeing device files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `/dev/*midi*` files are for the OSS interface, which is considered legacy.
Apparently, `CONFIG_SND_OSSEMUL` is not enabled in your kernel.

You are supposed to use the ALSA library for receiving MIDI data, but you could just read from `/dev/snd/midi*`-